# Trouble with quoted form of path in cURL with AppleScript

Tags: curl, applescript

This works:

```
do shell script "cURL -f http://mydomain/myfile.txt -o ~/Library/'Group Containers'/UBF8T346G9.Office/myFile.txt"
```

But extending the target path to include a second quoted folder fails:

```
do shell script "cURL -f http://mydomain/myfile.txt -o ~/Library/'Group Containers'/UBF8T346G9.Office/'User Content'/myFile.txt"
```

It raises an err:

Warning: Failed to create the file /Users/[username]/Library/Group

And in both cases, wrapping the full path in single quotes also fails at the same "Group" part of the path, eg:

```
do shell script "cURL -f http://mydomain/myfile.txt -o '~/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/myFile.txt'"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know what's causing the problem, but try quoting the entire path *except* for the `~/` at the beginning -- the shell only expands that to your home directory if it's not quoted. Also, check to make sure the single-quotes are plain ASCII single-quotes, not some fancy curly unicode quotes.

Comment: Thanks Gordon. I didn't realise the bit about ~/ and I tried without quoting that part (with plain ASCII single quotes) and it's still raising the error when there are two folder names with spaces in them in the path although quoting the whole first path example as you described resolves that issue.

Comment: Either: write the path out as in full instead of using the `~`, then put the whole thing in quotes: `"/Users/%you%/Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/User Content/myFile.txt"`; Or, as Gordon advised but I'll type explicitly, pull the tilde outside of the quoted path and leave the rest in quotes: `~/"Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/User Content/myFile.txt"`

Comment: Ahhhh. the folder 'User Content" appears that way in Finder but if I right-click and look at the Info, it's actually 'User Content.localized'

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use a backslash to escape spaces in paths. For example,

```
do shell script "cURL -f http://mydomain/myfile.txt -o ~/Library/Group\\ Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/User\\ Content.localized/Chart\\ Templates.localized/myFile.txt"
```

You can also use command `quoted form of the POSIX path of theInput` to properly escape a path given in the variable `theInput`. See the "Dealing with Files" section of Apple Technical Note TN2065, [do shell script in AppleScript](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2065/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10003093-CH1-SECTION4) for more details.

Comment: Thanks E.Harley. This is another thing I tried having read the Bash manual section on quoting and escaping but I got a syntax error in the Script Editor at the first space character : Expected """ but found unknown token. You can confirm by copy/pasting your example.

Comment: Whoops. Use double blackslashes to escape inside the double quoted string.

Comment: ahhhhhh! Thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that the solution is to use the correct name for the second folder! 
This is displayed as "User Content" in Finder but when examining with right-click/Info, it's actually "User Content.localized". So this works:

```
do shell script "cURL -f http://mydomain/myfile.txt -o ~/Library/'Group Containers'/UBF8T346G9.Office/'User Content.localized'/myFile.txt"
```

and so does this:

```
do shell script "cURL -f http://mydomain/myfile.txt -o ~/'Library/Group Containers/UBF8T346G9.Office/User Content.localized/myFile.txt'"
```